# MS- Acess database interface update from local

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am extremely new to Ms-Access. I have a central back end access database in server computer. And all the users have the front end user interface installed on their system.

Now, whenever I make any changes to the interface in my local, i need to re-install the updated interface on each of their system. Is their any way that i can do so that i will make the changes only on my local and it will be automatically reflected on all the users' systems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there are a couple of options that you can do to either fully or paritally automate this process.

Partial Automation
If you don't have a lot of users and you don't want to do a great deal of coding you can write a simple batchfile or vbs file which you set up on the users desktop as an icon. Batch file code would show the following type of information.

```
@Echo Off
REM Copy your file from server location to local user machine

xcopy "F:\ServerDirectory\databasename.mdb" "C:\ClientDirectory\databasename.mdb" /E /Y /R
```

Set this up on the users machine as an icon and whenever you want them to update their front end ask them to double click the icon. This will overwrite their client with whatever you place in the location on the server. It is advisable to create all table links to the database back end having UNC paths as well.

I have used this successfully for various applications - I make changes to the front end place in appropriate location on the server and then do a quick e-mail to people just to ask them to double click the bat file icon.

Full Automation
Programmatically set version control up using visual basic so the client checks version number of the client against a server number and if the client is not the latest will download a new version.

This is more involved and full instructions are available here.

[Front End Auto Update](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=265491)

Comment: IS there any way that i can protect this batch file such that the users can run the file but should not be able to open and the read the script inside the file.

Comment: You could probably hide the file in windows explorer and make the batch file read only. Similarly you could use something like active directory to restrict permissions.

Comment: Jean just realised I'd missed a few swtichtes in the code in the batch file they were /E /Y /R they are now added

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy an MS Access solutions like this, you need to decide whether to share the client MDB file between all users, or distribute copies to each user. It sounds like you have taken the second option. Each choice has merits and disadvantages. If you stay with the current approach, you might look at a scripting option to deploy updated client MDB files between users.

Comment: Thanks for the sugesstion...How can i implement the first option?

Comment: ( cc: @JeanGabriel ) re: *"How can i implement the first option?"* - DON'T DO THAT! Sharing the same copy of the front-end .mdb/.accdb file among multiple concurrent users can cause strange behaviour and can even corrupt data. **Always** ensure that every user has their own private copy of the front-end.

Comment: @GordThompson I mean how can i actually deploy the front-end on my local to all the users. I really could not follow the one on internet and blogs on this topic... any sugesstions please